# Trying to redirect one page to another, but my redirect rule doen't respond

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I've removed and/or combined a couple of pages on a site, And now I need to set up a 301 redirect.
I thougt doing so in my .htaccess was my best bet, but the rules I trying to add doesen't get noticed or something. They don't respond at all...

These are the rules I've tried so far:

```
Redirect 301 /?Page=sPage&sPage=Our-Store %{SERVER_NAME}?Page=sPage&sPage=About-Us
```

```
RewriteRule ^/?Page=sPage&sPage=Our-Store$ %{SERVER_NAME}?Page=sPage&sPage=About-Us[R=301,NC,L]
```

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^%{SERVER_NAME}$ [NC]
RewriteRule . %{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI}?Page=sPage&sPage=About-Us [R=301,L]
```

This last one messed up the CSS and JS src's...

I have this at the top:

```
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteBase /
```

Any suggestion?

**UPDATE : follow up question**
I have like 3000+ equal url strings with an ending ID that is different. How do I redirect all those requests?
This is the old url : `?Page=Tuninglist&Car=*`
And this is the new one : `?Page=Tuning&view=vehicle&type=Car&id=*`
* The value of `id=` is just integers...

Was hoping something like this could work, but no - got a 500 server error instead...

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^Page=Tuninglist&Car=([0-9]+)$
RewriteRule ^ ?Page=Tuning&view=vehicle&type=Car&id=$1 [R=301,L]
```

*EDIT: The 500 server error occurred because I had a `?` at the beginning of the condition.
The redirect now works, but the ending `id` value doesn't get included.
All I get is the correct page, but not the associated content based on that `id`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't match against  the query string in a redirect or rewrite rule, you need to do it using the `%{QUERY_STRING}` variable in a condition:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^Page=sPage&sPage=Our-Store$
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?Page=sPage&sPage=About-Us [R=301,L]
```